# Set local variable/fact in Drools rule engine

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I have a simple rule that is based on TaskPlanning example. It looks like this:

```
rule "It is better if user does not overexceeds its hours"
    when
        $emp : Employee()
        $task : Task( $taskType : taskType, employee == $emp)    
        accumulate( Task(employee == $emp);
                    $minutesOfEmplSpend : sum($taskType.getBaseDuration());
                    $emp.getMinutesAvailable() < $minutesOfEmplSpend
         )
    then
        scoreHolder.addMediumConstraintMatch(kcontext, 
$emp.getMinutesAvailable()-$minutesOfEmplSpend);    
end
```

And OK, it is working. But I would also like to add additional constraint there. **$task** variable has *isSerious* property, that holds boolean value. I would like it to be also taken into consideration when adding medium constraint.

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
scoreHolder.addMediumConstraintMatch(kcontext, 
$emp.getMinutesAvailable()-$minutesOfEmplSpend - ($task.isSerious == true ? 100 : 10) ));
```

But I am getting rules errors. I think I've tried everything - please at least point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Normal java code should work, try `$task.isSerious()` instead of `$task.isSerious`

Comment: That did the trick! I've sworn that I've tried that a hundred times!